# Image segmentation example using Min-Cut via BGL?

Tags: c++, boost, computer-vision

Does anyone know where to find a C++ example of Image Segmentation using Min-Cut via BGL? I know how to run Min-Cut via BGL using Edmunds-Karp Maximum Flow. What I am mostly interested in is the setup around building the graph from the image and transforming the Min-Cut result into the output of Image Segmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very good c++ implementation of image segmentation using graph0cuts can be found:
[at VGG iseg homepage](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/iseg/index.shtml). I'm not sure if they use BGL, but you can find where they run the graph-cut and replace this part with BGL.

Another more simple example can be [found here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~bagon/matlab.html#graphcut) look for the example there. It is a Matlab code - but it shows one way of building the energy function for the graph cut.

Comment: thank you Shai, btw I looked at your PhD Thesis and seems very interesting and very well made. It is no coincidence we are looking at this same topic :) When I asked this I was aiming to compare the Image segmentation solutions produced by Min-Cut via Submodular function minimization compared to the algorithmic one via BGL.